# Adding spaces in converted hex

Tags: php

I have this example data to be converted into hex

```
$converToHex = "##X27,5556789,A89,2*";

$convertedHex = bin2hex($converToHex);
```

how do I add spaces so that i can output something like this

```
23 23 58 32 37 2c 35 35 35 36 37 38 39 2c 41 38 39 2c 32 2a
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `chunk_split()` function in *php* to split the string into smaller parts.Use the code below :

```
<?php
    $converToHex = "##X27,5556789,A89,2*";

    $convertedHex = bin2hex($converToHex);
    echo chunk_split($convertedHex, 2, ' ');
?>
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)t function

In your case :

```
$converToHex = "##X27,5556789,A89,2*";
$convertedHex = bin2hex($converToHex);
$hexTab = str_split($convertedHex,2);

foreach($hexTab as $b){
    echo $b." ";
}
```

Comment: this would require 2 loops in php, one to split and one to add a space, the chunk_split() answer is the best answer in terms of efficiency.